# Why does a stream of smoke interact with a light source?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, convection

The photo in the top row shows the stages of interaction of a stream of smoke that is formed from a smoking stick with a light source. The light source turns on at the moment when the  smoke rises vertically upward, figure on the left, top row. As the air warms up, the stream begins to be attracted and eventually falls directly on the light source. But after a while the stream begins to push away from the light source. See the bottom row of pictures. If we propose an attraction mechanism looking only at the top row of drawings, we probably won’t be able to explain why the stream is then repelled. If we propose a mechanism of attraction and repulsion, looking at all the drawings, then aren’t we mistaken, since we don’t know whether or not the stream begins to attract or repel again. In other words, is this data sufficient to build a model?
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Can you repeat this experiment? Is the light source an incandescence light bulb? If you can repeat the experience and the the light source is also a heat source, this can be related to buoyancy and convection triggered by the heat source

Comment: @basics I repeated this experiment 30 times. I used a 15 watt 960 lm cold light bulb.

Comment: Now place a piece of glass between the bulb and the smoke.

Comment: @JonCuster Could you explain what for?

Comment: That isolates the smoke from any air currents caused by the heat of the bulb. Now you can let the air currents (mostly) develop, then expose the smoke stream to them.

Comment: @JonCuster The experiment is carried out as follows. First, a smoke flow is established. And then the lamp is turned on.

Comment: So, now turn it around. What you are likely seeing, as noted in the first comment, is the development of the convection currents from the heat of the bulb.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes it is, there is convection due to the heat of the bulb. This is explained in my post.

Comment: The behaviour of the smoke shows that there is a lot of turbulence in the air once the light bulb has warmed up. Turbulence is notoriously difficult to model in any quantitative way.

Comment: @gandalf61 Yes you are right. Nevertheless, we can give at least a qualitative explanation of why the jet is attracted to the light source and then repelled.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, the point is, you haven't showed that the smoke is attracted or repelled by the *light* source. It may be attracted/repelled by the heat source that happens to be the same object as the light source.

Comment: @ThePhoton The photograph shows a light source. But this source also produces heat. Therefore, convection occurs. This can explain attraction. But how can we explain repulsion?

Comment: @AlexTrounev All you are seeing is turbulence. I see no mystery here.

Comment: it's not repulsion. Heat off, no convection, smoke going back to original path. (as before, it's only my guess)

Comment: @basics All photographs are one series of events. The heat source is present in all photographs. But the convective flow around the lamp probably changes.